# Stack class issues in java

Tags: java, stack, logic

I have been having issues getting my stack based calculator to work in java. I know how to make a normal calculator but I want to try to challenge myself. What I do not understand is why is it that if I run this portion of my code in the main class it works but when I execute it outside it does not? It seems like my program outright ignores this logic and I can't wrap my head around why this is.

```
import java.util.Stack;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inp = "12 + 5 / 3";
        Stack<String> opStack = new Stack<String>();
        opStack.push("+");
        opStack.push("/");
        if (opStack.size() == 2)
            {
                if (opStack.peek() != "/" && opStack.peek() != "*")
                {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(opStack.peek()));
                }

            }
    }
}
```

This is a simple test of the logic, it works perfectly fine and just as intended

This however...

```
import java.util.Stack;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inp = "12 + 5 / 3";
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(calculate(inp)));
    }
    public static double calculate(String inp)
    {
        double val = 0;
        Stack<Double> numStack = new Stack<Double>();
        Stack<String> opStack = new Stack<String>();
        double res = 0;
        String op1 = "";
        String op2 = "";
        String[] arr = inp.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (isNumber(arr[i]))
            {
                if (i >= 2 && isNumber(arr[i - 1]))
                {
                    break;
                    //error message (can't have two numbers next to eachother)
                }
                val = Double.parseDouble(arr[i]);
                numStack.push(val);
                if (opStack.size() == 1)
                {
                    if (opStack.peek() == "*" || opStack.peek() == "/")
                    {
                        op1 = opStack.pop();
                        res = Operate(op1, numStack, res);
                        numStack.push(res);
                    }
                    else if (i == arr.length - 1)
                    {
                        op1 = opStack.pop();
                        res = Operate(op1, numStack, res);
                        numStack.push(res);
                    }
                }

                if (opStack.size() == 2)
                {
                    op1 = opStack.pop();
                    res = Operate(op1, numStack, res);
                    numStack.push(res);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                opStack.push(arr[i]);
                if (opStack.size() == 2)               //This is the exact same logic block I used ...
                                                       //previously, yet it still executes eventhough...
                                                       //opStack.peek() is "/"
                {
                    if (opStack.peek() != "/" && opStack.peek() != "*")
                    {
                        op1 = opStack.pop();
                        if (opStack.peek() != "/" && opStack.peek() != "*")
                        {
                            op2 = opStack.pop();
                            res = Operate(op2, numStack, res);
                            numStack.push(res);
                            opStack.push(op1);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            opStack.push(op1);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static boolean isNumber(String s)
    {
        try 
        {
            double dub = 0.0;
            dub = Double.parseDouble(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
         }
    }

    public static double Operate(String op, Stack<Double> stack, double d)
    {
        if (op == "+")
        {
            double last = stack.pop();
            double first = stack.pop();
            d = first + last;
            
        }
        else if (op == "-")
        {
            double last = stack.pop();
            double first = stack.pop();
            d = first - last;
        }
        else if (op == "*")
        {
            double last = stack.pop();
            double first = stack.pop();
            d = first * last;
        }
        else if (op == "-")
        {
            double last = stack.pop();
            double first = stack.pop();
            d = first / last;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

I tried it on multiple online debuggers to see the issue but after retrying the code block and realizing it was giving me different answers for the same logic I gave up on trying to brute force it.

Comment: You might be interested in this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java . However, that might or might not be the source of your problem.  Keep that in mind, as you run your code in a debugger.

Comment: Using `==` or `!=` to compare `String` Objects seems to be the source of  *a* problem. Your first example works because in `opStack.push("+");` and `opStack.peek() != "*"` , the  `"*"`  actually  reference the same Object, and the same for `"/"`. But, in your second example,  use of `==` fails because the operands are *not* the same Objects, even though their content is the same. So, use code like `if (op.equals("+"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the responce! I didn't realize that is why we have ".equals()" in Java. I thought it was just interchangable

Comment: Yes, it works now, I just need to tweak it